# Is This A Fraction?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was looking around to see some cool things you could do with a graphing calculator, and I came across this equation - [image]

I'm using [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/), and I'm not sure how I would do this. Is the equation above the same as [dx/dy]=[1−4/1−2][x/y]? If not, how can I do this in Desmos?

Comment: No, it's not the same. They're matrices, not fractions

Comment: Do you know how to do matrices in desmos

Comment: Ask [Neo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)).

Comment: @Lucian how is wikipedia going to help

Comment: It is a bit odd that they have a matrix of differentials on the LHS, but not actual derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are solving a system of differential equations
$$
x'(t) = x(t) - 4y(t) \\
y'(t) = x(t) - 2y(t)
$$
not one ODE.

This is exactly what allows you to make contour plots in 2D -- such graphs are in essence intersections of the 3D (t,x,y) solution with fixed-level planes...